Offsetting duplicate timestamps to make them unique
I have a list of timestamps that I need to offset by a second (or any other small increment of time) if it has a duplicate value on the sheet in order to add a small amount of variance to the timestamp.  output timestamp can be in a separate column.  Here's an example of the data set
I tried using a helper column with the following formula sum(countifs(A3, A:A, B3,B:B,c3,C:C)) and added a second for any duplicate value however, it doesn't make each value distinct.  I was thinking it could be possible to index duplicate entries and use that as multiplier to the second I add to the timestamp.  example if 3 entries have the timestamp 12:06:01 pm a helper column will index 1-3 a second column with then multiply the index by a second making the entries 12:06:02, 12:06:03, 12:06:04
Ive also considered maybe changing my sql statement to alter the lag value of duplicate timestamps.
sample data



USER_ID
TRUNC DSTAMP
TIME




487DUJE
9/23/2024
12:05:48 pm


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:32:32 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:30:37 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:31:21 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:31:22 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:32:32 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:33:25 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:33:25 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:51:41 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:54:47 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
10:20:16 am


487TEMP30
9/23/2024
12:18:14 pm


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:43:53 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:46:05 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:41:11 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:41:43 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:42:21 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:42:50 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:43:18 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:43:50 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:44:59 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:45:30 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:47:03 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:47:37 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
09:47:03 am


487TEMP30
9/23/2024
12:22:38 pm


487DUJE
9/23/2024
12:06:45 pm


487DUJE
9/23/2024
12:20:31 pm


487DUJE
9/23/2024
12:34:45 pm


487DUJE
9/23/2024
11:50:04 am


487SOMA
9/23/2024
12:21:37 pm


487DUJE
9/23/2024
12:18:17 pm


487CEMA
9/23/2024
10:13:36 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
10:15:05 am


487CEMA
9/23/2024
10:15:05 am




Just adding 1 second might solve the duplicated rows, but it might become duplicated with other previously not duplicated rows.
Here is a solution adding random noise as seconds with decimals using NORM.S.INV(RAND()) which produces a random number with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.

A, B, C: is the input data
D: random number, this can be incorporated into ColumnE, I left it to show the mean and standard deviation of random numbers, see row 38 and 39.
E: add random number as seconds ColumnE + ColumnD/86400

Applied conditional formatting to show duplicated values for columns C and E.


What is the chance to still have duplications after?

@rotabor it is not zero, it can happen with enough rows. But advantages: there is no VBA, calculation is row by row - no heavy computing lookups/countifs. Average and standard deviation of time is not affected by noise. Disadvantage: every time you change a cell value, it gets recalculated, always copy paste it as "values".

I can provide you with the fast VBA solution (for Excel-365) - no manual actions, no time intersections*, zero time performance:

The code:
Option Explicit

Sub Restamp()
  Dim rc As Long
  rc = [A1].End(xlDown).Row - 1
  First rc
  Main rc
  Last
End Sub

Private Sub First(i As Long)
  Dim a, r As Range
  [D1] = "Seq#"
  [D2].Formula2 = "=SEQUENCE(" & i & ")"
  Set r = [D2].Resize(i, 1)
  r.NumberFormat = "General"
  a = r
  r = a
  [A1].CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=[B:B], Key2:=[A:A], Key3:=[C:C], Header:=xlYes
End Sub

Private Sub Main(i As Long)
  Dim a, j As Long, id As String, d As Date, t As Date
  Dim n As Date, s As Date, x As Date
  x = Now()
  s = 1 / 86400
  a = [a2].Resize(i, 3)
  id = a(1, 1): d = a(1, 2): t = a(1, 3)
  For j = 2 To UBound(a)
    If a(j, 1) = id And a(j, 2) = d Then
      If a(j, 3) <= t Then
        t = t + s
        a(j, 3) = t
      Else
        t = a(j, 3)
      End If
    Else
      id = a(j, 1): d = a(j, 2): t = a(j, 3)
    End If
  Next
  [a2].Resize(i, 3) = a
  Debug.Print "Execution time "; Int(86400 * (Now() - x)); " s"
End Sub

Private Sub Last()
  [A1].CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=[D:D], Header:=xlYes
  [A1].CurrentRegion.Columns(4).Clear
End Sub

Having the data sheet active run the Restamp macro.
Prerequisites:

Data should be organized as depicted (column titles can vary).
TRUNC_DSTAMP is expected to be the date only (the time part is 0).
TIME is expected to be the time only (the date part is 0).

Limitations:

Midnight trespass is not controlled.
Time equality comparison is expected to be exact (it's dependent on how timestamps are obtained). If timestamps are gotten from time text representation without parts of seconds, it should work.

The solution is based on preliminary sort of data by the date then by the user id. This allows to process data in the single run. Time intersection resolves by joining to the sequence the next time which less or equal the last time in the sequence thus the timestamp sequence {00:00:00, 00:00:00,00:00:00,00:00:00,00:00:02} will be resolved to {00:00:00, 00:00:01,00:00:02,00:00:03,00:00:04}
To pass over the limitations the more sophisticated algorithm is required.

* Timestamp intersection is when the modified timestamp can match the next timestamp(s). E. g. the timestamp sequence {00:00:00, 00:00:00,00:00:00,00:00:00,00:00:02} will be modified to {00:00:00, 00:00:01,00:00:02,00:00:03,00:00:02} which causes the third value matches the fifes one.

I tried running this script and It didn't work.  can you show me the applied steps.

version 2402 excel

=LET(r,$F$2:$F$20000,Q2+TIME(0,0,MATCH(ROW(),FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(r),r&$P$2:$P$20000&$Q$2:$Q$20000=F2&P2&Q2),0)-1)))  This was my input and the formula doesn't work

:-( It should be =LET(r,$F$2:$F$20000,Q2+TIME(0,0,MATCH(ROW(),FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(r),1,ROW(r)),r&$P$2:$P$20000&$Q$2:$Q$20000=F2&P2&Q2),0)-1))

yeah it works.  however when applied to such a large number of rows the formula appears to break.

Yes, functions have limits. How many rows you process?

17-20k rows on any given day typically

With Excel 365 this formula in cell D3
=LET(cnt,COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A3,B$2:B2,B3,C$2:C2,C3),
IF(cnt>0,XLOOKUP(C3,C$2:C2,C$2:C2,,0,-1)+TIME(0,0,cnt),C3))

Add to the TIME function's cnt value the required offset. (cnt*offset)


Can you check it for >100000 records?

I tested, it works well.
